# Connecting Ruby on Rails to an External Database

Tags: sql-server, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an MSSQL external DB and I need to connect to it.

I made a new entry in the database.yml

```
external_database:
   adapter: sqlserver
   host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   database: Trader
   username: name
   password: pw
   timeout : 5000
```

and made a model file in app/models/database.rb

```
class Database < ActiveRecord::Base
   establish_connection(:external_database)
   self.table_name = 'dbo.Trade'
end
```

What models/controllers do I need to access something in my database? I have no idea even if I'm connected properly to the database.

There is [this case](http://www.paultastic.com/showpage/Grabbing-Data-From-Foreign-Database-Using-Rails) where a guy uses PHP, but this seems to eliminate the point of Ruby.
[This link](http://birds-eye.net/rails/app-models-external-database-connections.htm) just shows errors after completion in the view where you do the actual value retrieving.

Comment: There is *no* PHP in the case you point out. Maybe you should post the errors your code is producing? How are we supposed to help, when we don't *have* your external database to try connecting to?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know if I'm properly connected to the database. When I enter any different values for host and database, I get an error saying such things don't exist (I test by typing rails console). If there is no PHP, then I'm mistaken. I tried that case. I did side = con.execute("select side from dbo.Trade") and it returns -1. Edit: and I had to remove .fetch_row, so I assume that it cannot do anything to -1. Is there a way to test that I'm properly connecting?

Comment: Regarding the second link, I get errors saying that I need to have ')' instead of commas in the retrieving line.

Comment: Is this the primary database for you app? Or is this a secondary database you're trying to establish a connection to?